# How to subscribe to particular object in angular2 store

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx-store

I am implementing ngrx store in my angular2 application,

Store reducer looks like below with two objects,

```
export function loadSuccessNamesAction(state: StoreData, action: loadSuccessNamesAction): StoreData {
    const namesDataState = Object.assign({}, state);
   namesDataState .isSpinner = false;
   namesDataState .names = action.payload.names;
   return namesDataState ;
}

export function loadSuccessSubjectAction(state: StoreData, action: loadSuccessSubjectAction): StoreData {
    const subjectDataState = Object.assign({}, state);
   subjectDataState .isSpinner = false;
   subjectDataState .subject = action.payload.subject;
   return namesDataState ;
}
```

In my component i want to get namesDataState  only, so how can i subscribe to only one object in  store.

Currently I am subscribing to whole store, instead of that i want to subscribe to only first object.

Any solutions will be helpful, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [distinctUntilKeyChanged](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/distinctUntilKeyChanged.ts)

```
this.store.select('namesDataState')
  //Only emit when any name has changed
  .distinctUntilKeyChanged(
    //Key to filter on
    'name',
    //Optional comparison function if you have a specific way of comparing keys 
    (x, y) => x.name === y.name)
  .pluck('name')
  .subscribe((name: any) => {});
```